# What's the appropriate Microsoft Office 2007 version for charities?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, license

I work for a small charity in the UK. Like many charities we rely completely on donations and so have to make our money go as far as possible.

We've had a copy of Office 2007 Home and Student Edition donated to us. Are we allowed to use it? On the Microsoft website it specifies that it's intended for households, which would exclude us, but in the programs themselves it says "non-commercial use", which does include us.

Is there anything in the license terms that would stop us as a charity using Home and Student Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guys advised I fired off an email to the help address for Microsoft's online store. I got the following response:

> Dear Mr North,
>
> Thank you for your e-mail.
>
> It is no problem at all for you to use an Office Home and Student edition in the context described by you. For further inquiries about Office products please click on this link:
>
> http://emea.microsoftstore.com/UK/
>
> Please feel free to contact us if you should have any further questions. We are happy to help.
>
> Kind Regards
>
> Manfred Löchtermann

So it looks like it's fine after all.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question: probably not. You'd need to ask a lawyer or a Microsoft licensing rep. I can't understand their T&C's anymore.

I'll probably lose karma for this as it doesn't answer your question--but why wouldn't your charity at least *investigate* the use a competing office suite that doesn't classify users, or discriminate against terms of endeavor?

The most popular office suite that doesn't have any sort of use conditions would be [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org).

If your money is that tight but you have some time, evaluate it. There is no per-seat licensing (the license *gives* you additional rights, and it's zero-cost) and it's incredibly compatible with Microsoft Office, although it is not perfect.

Comment: We'll have a proper look at this in the future, when we don't already have a copy of MS Office ready to go.

For now I'm going to accept my answer with the response from MS, as it answers the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to contact Microsoft in the UK and explain the situation & they'll give you the correct information.

The only thing to consider is that if it has been previously installed you might have a problem activating the software. In that case contacting Microsoft is the best advice I can give here.

Comment: +1 for asking Microsoft, they might even support your cause ;-)

Comment: -1 for glib answer. Charities can't afford to be caught out of compliance.

Comment: @Broam - better now?

Comment: Aye, much.

Answer (score 0):

What you possibly need is the Microsoft Open License for Charities, but trying to find UK specific information without going via a Microsoft Partner is a challenge in itself.  Start with

https://partner.microsoft.com/UK/licensing/licensingprograms/ltvolumelicensing/vlopenlicense

and see how you get on from there

Comment: In Canada, the only way to get Charilty MOLP is from a select group of MS retailers. We have no choice and I thought UK had gone the same route.  Good luck in your seach.  Hope you find a good reseller.

Answer (score 0):

I know in Canada that would be a license violation. Not sure if the UK is the same as in Canada but MS has a very attractive Charity and Not for Profit license program.  Just looked and Office Standard Charity is CAN$83.00 Worth chatting with a friendly reseller.  In a past position, I saved my charity/not-for-profit clinets thousands of dollars on this program.